# Random number generration in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I uniformly distributed the sensor nodes using
`intuniform (0,1000);`However,everytime when I started the simulation from beginnig, all the sensor nodes is placed at the same position.Then I used the `srand(time(NULL))` the result is again same.For example, in the first run sn[1] position is 
(150, 167), it is same in the second run.I want to change it.The program should not memorize it.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMNeT++ uses different pseudo random number generators than standard C++. It is a core feature of OMNeT++ that running the same simulation twice yields exactly the same result. The function srand changes the seed of the standard C++ generator only. You can also change the seed of OMNeT++ generators, but more likely you want to start a different **run** of your simulation. This will automatically use a different (well chosen) seed.